# How do I slice a file to pieces and restore it in Javascript FileApi

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash, fileapi

I'm trying to create ajax file upload but I have encountered an error with it, when you upload a file that is larger than for example:800MB google chrome crash.

So I thought to cut it into pieces and then restore it,but how do I do this?

Comment: _"So I thought to cut it into pieces and then restore it,but how do I do this?"_ Do you mean create several files from single file, upload the several files, then combine the several files back into single file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript FileReader API  that helps to create chunks and send it to the server. The mechanism is simple but if you are using small chunk size chrome might crash again if you are uploading asynchronously because of the looping through all the chucks.

Which you can solve the by using Webworkers, Javascript Webworkers acts as separate threads and finally use Websockets if possible.

Few Resources to implement all the

- [MDN FileReader API](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjkq8iawfTJAhXDBY4KHbzpCJMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FFileReader&usg=AFQjCNEfLxCALbO2Dr8HnUrwN1v0TSCxvg&sig2=N-i8RLUbTPQQPYcz9owM8A)
- [Article Explains with these features](http://kongaraju.blogspot.in/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html)
- [HTML5 Rocks File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)